# JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "jqueryLibrary/css/ui-lightness/images/Calendar2.jpg",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                document.getElementById('startDate').value = dateText
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "jqueryLibrary/css/ui-lightness/images/Calendar2.jpg",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                document.getElementById('endDate').value = dateText
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="demo">
    <div class="date">
        <label class="label">Start Date</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    </div>
    <div class="date">
        <label class="label">End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two datePickers in one page. I used two jQuery codes, one for each datepicker.
However, they are almost the same and the only difference is the ID.

How can I keep one jQuery code for both datepickers? (i.e. `id='datepicker'` and `id='datepicker2'`)

Comment: I doubt it makes much difference but you can also do the value set `document.getElementById('startDate').value = dateText;` in jQuery-style as `$('#startDate').val(dateText);`.

Answer (score 3):

Give a class to the inputs so

```
<input type="text" class="pickable" id="datepickerblah" />
```

Then

```
 $(".pickable").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",
     buttonImage: "jqueryLibrary/css/ui-lightness/images/Calendar2.jpg",
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
         $(this).value = dateText;
     }
 });
```

Comment: Pickable, what a great class name. +1

Comment: Note she has different onSelect functions - you'd also need to tie the target element to the date picker somehow, e.g. storing a `.data()` on the pickers individually before calling the common function

Comment: @Rup, thanks didn't catch that, updated, accounting for different ids

Answer (score 1):

Use a class and intialize using:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="mydatepicker"  />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="mydatepicker"  />

$( ".mydatepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "jqueryLibrary/css/ui-lightness/images/Calendar2.jpg",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                        document.getElementById('endDate').value = dateText
                    }

    });
});
```

Comment: But the first datePicker sets the startDate value, not the endDate

Comment: true i suggest dave's solution

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"  />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="datepicker"  />

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "jqueryLibrary/css/ui-lightness/images/Calendar2.jpg",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

        this.value = dateText;
    }
});
```

As stated on the jQuery UI website, `this` in the `onSelect` callback refers to the input box used with the datepicker, so one datepicker would refer to `#datepicker`, and the other to `#datepicker2`.

**Edit**

Just noticed your putting the date into a different box, in which this would work:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker startdate"  />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="datepicker enddate"  />

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "jqueryLibrary/css/ui-lightness/images/Calendar2.jpg",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var elem = "startDate";
        if( $(this).hasClass("enddate") {
            elem = "endDate"
        }
        document.getElementById(elem).value = dateText;
    }
});
```